# UPDATE do mysql, não recebe o valor da função no PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho essa função:

```
$id = pega_assunto_por_nome_menu($_GET['assunto'])['id'];
```

Que me retorna o valor do id, caso use `echo $id;`
Mas quando vou fazer o update no mysql, ele não funciona.

Aparece este erro:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 3

A linha seis é a definição do `id = {$id};`

```
$atualiza = "UPDATE assuntos SET
            nome_menu = '{$nome_menu}'
            WHERE id = {$id}";
```

Se utilizo o var_dump, este é o resultado.

```
$assunto = pega_assunto_por_nome_menu($_GET['assunto']);
var_dump($assunto); 

array (size=10)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string 'Sobre a Preliminartes' (length=21)
  'nome_menu' => string 'Sobre a Preliminartes' (length=21)
  2 => string 'sobre_a_preliminarte' (length=20)
  'nome_menu_slug' => string 'sobre_a_preliminarte' (length=20)
  3 => string '1' (length=1)
  'posicao' => string '1' (length=1)
  4 => string '1' (length=1)
  'visivel' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: não seria `$id = pega_assunto_por_nome_menu($_GET['assunto']['id'])`; ?

Comment: Aparece este erro se troco, Illegal string offset 'id'

Comment: Debug esse seu array antes de passar para a função. `var_dump($_GET['assunto']);`

Comment: faz assim : `$assunto = pega_assunto_por_nome_menu($_GET['assunto']);` e depois `var_dump($assunto);` e coloca o resultado aqui...

Comment: Coloquei o resultado no final da pergunta

Comment: @AlêMoraes, adicionei uma resposta ali, faça o teste. Se não funcionar deixe nos comentários da resposta.

Comment: Ainda não consegui, coloquei o código todo desse estudo neste link:  http://pastebin.com/zjwAmbDx

Comment: @AlêMoraes conseguiu?

Comment: Consegui, ainda não entendi direito, o porquê, kkk, mas no action do form, ele aplicava a id em vez do nome_menu_slug, daí a função retornava zero sempre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(SEMPRE) Faça uma validação nas variáveis antes de realizar qualquer operação com o banco de dados:

```
// Valida se a variável está vazia
if (empty($_GET['assunto']))
  die('Assunto não informado.');

// Recebe todos os dados da função
$assunto = pega_assunto_por_nome_menu($_GET['assunto']);

// Verifica se recebeu algum ID da função anterior
if (empty($assunto) || empty($assunto['id']))
  die('Nenhum resultado encontrado.');

// ¬¬
$id = $assunto['id'];

// Dependendo de onde você recebe essa variável é bom valida-la também
$nome_menu = filter_var($_GET['nome_menu']); // Caso a validação falhe, será retornado FALSE

// Verifica se a string  filtrada é valida
if ($nome_menu === FALSE)
   die('Nome inválido.');

$atualiza = "UPDATE assuntos SET
        nome_menu = '{$nome_menu}'
        WHERE id = {$id}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Troque essa linha: `$id = pega_assunto_por_nome_menu($_GET['assunto'])['id'];`

Por esta linha: `$id = pega_assunto_por_nome_menu($_GET['assunto']['id']);`

Comment: Aparece este erro se troco,  Illegal string offset 'id'

Comment: Realmente, o erro está na estrutura do array.
troque isso: `$id = pega_assunto_por_nome_menu($_GET['assunto']['id']);`
por isso:
`$id = pega_assunto_por_nome_menu($_GET['assunto'][1]['id']);`

Comment: Aparece Illegal string offset 'id'

Comment: Coloquei o código todo desse estudo neste link:  http://pastebin.com/zjwAmbDx

Answer (score 0):

Olá, a sua função tem que estar retornando alguma coisa... `return $algo;`. Se na sua aplicação estiver do jeito que você passou, não vai funcionar, o índice ID está fora do parâmetro da função. 
Troque isso:

```
$id = pega_assunto_por_nome_menu($_GET['assunto'])['id'];
```

por isso:

```
$id = pega_assunto_por_nome_menu($_GET['assunto']['id']);
```

Tendo então o valor dentro da variável $id, debug a mesma: `var_dump($id);` para conferir.

Comment: Com o var_dump($id): string '1' (length=1)

Comment: Faça o seguinte então: quando for dar update, utilize isso:
`$atualiza = "UPDATE assuntos SET nome_menu = '" . $nome_menu . "' WHERE id = '" . $id . "';`
Mais por desencargo, pois seu id está vindo como string.

Comment: Ainda não consegui, coloquei o código todo desse estudo neste link:  http://pastebin.com/zjwAmbDx

Comment: Na linha 6 - `$id = pega_assunto_por_nome_menu($_GET['assunto'])['id'];`, mude para isso: `$id = pega_assunto_por_nome_menu($_GET['assunto']);`. Se mesmo assim, der o erro, qual o erro que ele te retorna? Na linha 33, debug aquele `$inteiro`. Logo após você atribuir valor ao `$inteiro`, faça o seguinte comando: `$atualiza = "UPDATE assuntos SET nome_menu = 'teste' WHERE id = " . $inteiro;` . com isso é pra atualizar o nom_menu como "teste" no seu bd, se não for, o erro está no seu id. OBS: verifique antes do teste se não tem nada NOTNULL na tabela...

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion na linha 9 - echo $id;

Comment: O erro está aí, esse `$id` tem que ter um valor tipo string ou inteiro, não array. debug esse `$id` e me passe o valor... Valor tem que ser assim: `$id = '4';`